# Python program for monitoring filesystem changes

Tags: python, python-3.x

My target device has some memory restriction and i cannot add any extra python packages except the default python packages
I need to write a python program that monitor a file present in my target and if any write operation happened to that file by any program, then my monitoring program
should get a notification event.
I saw may implementation using watchdog package but i am restricted not to use the same.
Is there any similar implementation possible with default python package.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion for this task.

Comment: which operating system? could potentially use the os for example on linux `inotify` and specifically `inotifywait` http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/iwatch.1.html, with a custom wrapper around it, if there's a lot of files it'll become cumbersome to `os.path.walk` the directory with python checking for file `mtimes`

Comment: i am using linux Os